# Laravel Integer to Float or Decimal MySQL Column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a current db table called scores that has 2 columns `user_score` and `approved_score` which are both Integer.

After initial launch we have decided to make things more exact by add a decimal to a score. So instead of getting a 10 you could get a 10.40 or a 10.47 ect. I am just curious on:

- Should I change it to a `decimal` or a `float` based on us needing 2
  decimal points with trailing 0. So: `$table-> decimal('user_score', 8,
  2)->change();`
- Will that mess up data in there already? Like will a
  score of 123 stay 123? We rank based on score so the higher the
  better.

Comment: Just a thought here, but you could keep it as an integer and then divide by 100 when displaying the scores to reflect it as a decimal. That's how Stripe stores transactions amounts, as a whole number, then it's up to the application's display logic to convert to a decimal format.

Comment: The trouble is there are scores already in there so I dont want to have a new score of 1000 (which would equal 10 in your solution) be better than a current score of 10

Comment: @btl if you want to add that as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A float would be more appropriate in this case, it doesn't sound like you need a high number of precision points after the decimal place. The data should not be impacted by changing the column type, so long as your values are not currently larger than `(8,2)`.

Also, updating your existing data if you kept the column as an integer would be trivial as all you would need to do is `UPDATE column SET column=column*100`.